# NVCC compiles the Eigen library, and the resize of MatrixXd in the structure at runtime fails

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, eigen, nvcc

I am using the [Eigen library version 3.3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) with g++ 5.4 and CUDA 8.0 in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

confusing things happened while writing the code. 
A crash occurs when I try to resize Eigen::MatrixXd in a structure

the structure is as follows.

```
struct cudaCopy{
      struct s_path_info *nodes_parents
      struct s_path_info *nodes_children
      ...
}
```

the s_path_info structure is as follows.

```
struct s_path_info{
    Eigen::MatrixXd supps;
    Eigen::MatrixXd residu;
    ...
```

The problems are as follows.

```
struct cudaCopy *mem;
mem = (struct cudaCopy*)malloc(sizeof(struct cudaCopy));
```

and

```
mem->nodes_parents = (struct s_path_info*)malloc(50 * sizeof(struct s_path_info))
for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
    mem->nodes_parents[i].supps.resize(1, 1); // ERROR
```

Here is the backtrace that GDB execute the code.

> ```
> #0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x1) at malloc.c:2949
> #1  0x000000000040a538 in Eigen::internal::aligned_free (ptr=0x1) at ../Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:177
> #2  0x000000000040f3e8 in Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_free<true> (ptr=0x1) at ../Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:230
> #3  0x000000000040cdd4 in Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_delete_auto<double, true> (ptr=0x1, size=7209728) at ../Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:416
> #4  0x000000000040d085 in Eigen::DenseStorage<double, -1, -1, -1, 0>::resize (this=0x6e1348, size=20, rows=20, cols=1) at ../Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:406
> #5  0x000000000040ba9e in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::resize (this=0x6e1348, rows=20, cols=1) at ../Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:293
> #6  0x000000000040697f in search::islsp_EstMMP_BF_reuse (this=0x7fffffffe4b0) at exam.cu:870
> #7  0x0000000000404f33 in main () at exam.cu:422
> ```

interestingly, the following works well.

```
mem->nodes_children = (struct s_path_info*)malloc(10*50*sizeof(struct s_path_info))
for(int i=0; i<10*50; i++){
    mem->nodes_children[i].supps.resize(1, 1); // OK
```

I can't understand why nodes_parents can not be resized.

I would appreciate any comments on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You set `nodes_parents` to uninitialized memory, that means the constructor of `s_path_info` (and thus of its members) is never called.
Instead of `struct s_path_info *nodes_parents` you should simply write:

```
std::vector<s_path_info> nodes_parents;
```

And your main `cudaCopy` should just be a stack variable:

```
cudaCopy mem;
```

Generally, do not use `malloc` inside C++, especially not for non PODs.

N.B.: The fact that it worked with `nodes_children` is likely by pure coincidence.